# readLines() is not working on Windows for special characters

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `readLines()` to grep some string from a file. After trying on RStudio, I found it is working on Mac, but failing on Windows.

Here are results from a two-line text file.

Mac:

```
> readLines('test.txt', encoding = 'UTF-8', skipNul = T)
[1] "       Nrrrr\316\001\032e\363\f\fY            01     Apple"                    
[2] "                                              02     Orange"
```

Windows:

```
> readLines('test.txt', encoding='UTF-8', skipNul = T)
[1] "       Nrrrr蝄001"
Warning message:
In readLines("test.txt", encoding = "UTF-8", skipNul = T) :
  incomplete final line found on 'test.txt'
```

As these text files are provided by another company, it might be a little time consuming to communicate with them for the file format.

I wonder if there is any way to fix the issue on Windows?

--- EDIT ---

Using `readr::read_lines` it can avoid stopping at the line that contains special characters, but it seems not able to get the rest characters of that line:

```
> readr::read_lines('test.txt')
[1] "       Nrrrr\xce"                                             
[2] "                                                02     orange"
```

Comment: Have you tried `readr::read_lines()`? I believe there is meant to be encoding handing built in to this package

Comment: According to this Github [issue](https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/issues/38), you may consider the approach `readLines(file("test.txt", encoding = "UTF-8"), enconding = "UTF-8", skipNul = TRUE)` if you want to stay in `base`.

Comment: Thanks @kevin.arseneau. `readr` is better than `base`, just updated my question with the outputs. Also, `readLines` with `file(...)` is not working at my side.

Comment: what error are you receiving with the `file()` connection?

Comment: @kevin.arseneau  `Error in readLines(file("test.txt", encoding = "UTF-8"), enconding = "UTF-8",  :   unused argument (enconding = "UTF-8")`. If I remove the "encoding" argument of `readLines` it returns the same as the "Windows part" in my question.

Comment: Is the typo in `encoding` only in your comment?

Comment: @kevin.arseneau ah.. I haven't noticed the typo. Updated my question with the `readLines()` + `file()` connection.